# jssor slider having issue for safari browser

Tags: jssor

I have embed jssor slider to my webpage. It works fine in all browser but for safari it slows down while slide.
Slider is having page size. means width:100%; height:100%;
Problem is only for **safari**.

Comment: What's the version of browser and os?

Comment: os: Windows 7, Browser Version: safari 5.1.7, Screen Resolution: 1366 x 786

Comment: Can I access your demo online?

Comment: It helps to set $HWA option to false